# How to find ArrayList containing Object

Tags: java

I have a method from which i am returning object like

```
public static Object login(DataManager dataManager, String userName, String password)       
    ArrayList<LoginCredentialsBean> loginCredentialsList = new ArrayList<LoginCredentialsBean>();       
    String authenticated = "false";     
    Connection connection = null;       
    try {           
        connection  = dataManager.getConnection();          
    } catch (Exception e) {         
         return ("Having problem in connectiong to databaste: " + e.getMessage());          
    }       
    if (connection != null) {           
         try {                                       
             ...                     
             try {                   
                 ResultSet rs = prepStatement.executeQuery();                   

                 try {                      
                     while (rs.next()) {
                         ...                             
                         loginCredentialsList.add(new LoginCredentialsBean(roleId, orgaCode, passwordExpiryDate, date, status, language));                                                          
                        authenticated = "true";                          
                     } //end of while()                                                  
                 } finally {                     
                     rs.close();                     
                 }                   
             } finally {
                 prepStatement.close();                  
             }                
             if (authenticated.equals("true")) {                     
                updateUserLogByInserting(connection, userName);                  
             }

         } catch(SQLException e) {               
             System.out.println("Could not login from dataabse:" + e.getMessage());              
         } finally {                 
             dataManager.putConnection(connection);                          
         }                  
    }       
    if (authenticated.equals("true")) {                 
        return loginCredentialsList;            
    } else {        
        return authenticated;           
    }       
} //end of login()
```

Now i am testing it like

```
public static void main(String... args) {

    MoneyTreeServices moneyTreeServices = new MoneyTreeServices();

    Object result = moneyTreeServices.login("Admin", "cbas1234");       
    if (result instanceof ArrayList<?>) {

        System.out.println("ArrayList instance");           
    }       
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

It returns me result like

```
ArrayList instance
[pk.mazars.moneyTree.bean.LoginCredentialsBean@b7ec5d]
```

I want to ask i am using condition like `ArrayList<?>`. How can i check that ArrayList that contain LoginCredentialsBean object. Like when i use

```
if (result instanceof ArrayList<LoginCredentialsBean>) {

}
```

i get error that

```
Can not perform instanceof check against parameterized type ArrayList<LoginCredentialsBean>. Use the form ArrayList<?>
```

I want to check instanceof ArrayList and arraylist has LoginCredentialsBean ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that **you can't**.  Generics are implemented via type erasure - they're effectively a compile-time syntactic sugar to ensure you don't put an `Integer` into a `List<String>`.

The runtime objects themselves, however, are just the raw types.  An instance of `ArrayList` doesn't *know* that it's an `ArrayList<String>` (or rather, that it was assigned to a variable with that generic type).  So when you interrogate it with reflection, you cannot get any generic type info.

There are two broad types of solution I can think of.  One is to iterate over the list contents and check *their* dynamic type - if the first element is a `LoginCredentialsBean`, for example, then it's reasonable to assume that you have a `List<LoginCredentialsBean>`.  This won't work for empty lists though, which could be a problem, and can potentially give false positives (e.g. a `List<Object> allParameters` might happen to have a `LoginCredentialsBean` as its first element...)

The other is to explicitly pass metadata objects around - so in this case you'd return the `Object` from the `login` method, along with a token which describes what type of object it is.  This could be a simple enum constant; or going to the other extreme you could make the tokens generically typed, such that the compiler can check this against the type of what you're returning and ensure that the tokens are type-correct.

But in any case, `instanceof` is too little (information), too late.

---

Mind you, your `login` method looks... odd.  I don't think it should return an `Object` at all, as that's just lazy and completely subverting the static type system which would help you here.  Rather, I think it should just return a `List<LoginCredentialsBean>` containing the credentials that pertain to the given login.

You have three different paths where you return.  The first is if an exception is encountered when connecting to the database - *in which case you should throw an exception*!  Returning a string with the error details is very atypical and confusing - an exceptional condition should be handled as an `Exception`, that's what they're for.

The other two situations are ones where you're able to look up definitive results.  For the failed login case, I would just return an empty list (i.e. this username/password has no credentials whatsoever), while returning the populated list during a successful login.

If you strongly want to be able to distinguish between a login failure, and a successful login (with no credentials), then perhaps return a compound object instead, such as:

```
class LoginStatus {
    final boolean authenticated;
    final List<LoginCredentialsBean> credentials;
}
```

Either way, the caller knows exactly what they're getting back, and can call methods on it appropriately without having to call `instanceof` and typecast.

Comment: hhmm thanks. To be very honest yup it is odd and thanks for pointing me:) First i thought i should make a boolean field in my LoginCredentialBean, but then i thought that LoginCredentialBean  instance should only be created when user successfully authenticate and then i come with with this bad design code :). Anyways i make boolean field in my bean and first it is false, and on successfull authentication i set it to true and just return List of LoginCredentialBean. Is it sound Ok to you ?

Comment: I can assume that if my list is empty then user has fail to authenticate because i fill my list only when I'll get successfully login.

Answer (score 1):

Parameterized type info is erased at compile time and `instanceof` is resolved at (fanfare) runtime - that is why you get that error.

What you could do is iterate over the elements in the `List` and `instanceof` them.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You have to check it twice.

```
if (result instanceof ArrayList<?>) {
 System.out.println("ArrayList instance");
 //cast
 ArrayList<LoginCredentialsBean> list = (ArrayList<LoginCredentialsBean>) result;

  ///..check if list contains LoginCredentialsBean
 for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
  if(list.get(i) instanceof LoginCredentialsBean){
   System.out.println("LoginCredentialsBean instance");
  }  
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing like "ArrayList that contain LoginCredentialsBean"
ArrayList contains Objects, all the time.

you must iterate over the list and check each object:

```
for (Object o: result) {
     if (!(o instanceof LoginCredentialsBean)) {
           //Fail
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `contains(Object o)` to check whether the ArrayList contains your object. With the `instanceof List` to check whether the given object is a List. Because of type erasure at runtime the generic type of the List wont be available

Answer (score 0):

If your `login` method returns an `Object` type there is no way to check this the way you try.
Type parameters exist only on compile-time due to type erasure. You need to check if retuned object is a `List` or `Collection` or just `Iterable`, then iterate throuh it and check every item, if it is a instance of `LoginCredentialsBean`.

However, your code is an example of bad design. A method that returns a `String` or a list is just wrong. To make it right:

- make it return `List<LoginCredentialsBean>`
- throw a checked exception if authentication fails

`public static List<LoginCredentialsBean> login(DataManager dataManager, String userName, String password) throws AuthenticationException {...}`

Note: Use `boolean` to keep logical data instead of `"true"` or `"false"` strings.